# From Nodejs to Jxcore multithreading

Tags: node.js, multithreading, jxcore

I learned that [JXcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore) support **multithreading**.

I built it and now I run my app with : *./jxcore/jx app.js* instead of *node app.js*

Is multithreading automatically activated or something else is needed (in the command or in my app.js code) ?

Comment: Looks like you need to [define tasks](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/blob/master/doc/api/jxcore-tasks.markdown) that should run in separate threads. FWIW, it looks like active development of JXcore has been halted, so it's probably not wise to use it for new production software.

Comment: Then I have to give up js for C++ or something else if I want to use multithreading, as JXcore seems to be the only one alternative to Node.js. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: Why do you want/need multithreading?

Comment: To optimize a real-time multiplayer game, besides the optimization of the bandwidth usage.

Comment: If you have specific performance bottlenecks, this is a good place to share them. You may be able to benefit from Node's [`cluster`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module, for instance.